# Crazy JavaScript Output In Web Browsers

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm creating some HTML anchors, with JavaScript, from a web API.

```
scheduleitems += '<li class="link"><a href="javascript:makeRequest(getUrl("' + date + '"), getTodaysChapter);"><span class="date"><time datetime="' + date + '">' + datereadable + '</time></span> <span class="reference bookchapter">' + book + ' ' + chapter + '</span></a></li>';
```

That all seems pretty straight-forward.
It's a list of anchors.

That code should end up looking similar to this...

```
<a href="javascript:makeRequest(getUrl("2018-02-05"), getTodaysChapter);">
```

But, it ends up looking very strange (and different in different web browsers).

Microsoft Edge:

```
<a href="javascript:makeRequest(getUrl(" gettodayschapter);"="" 2018-02-05"),=""><span class="date"><time datetime="2018-02-05">Mon Feb 05 2018</time></span> <span class="reference bookchapter">Amos 1</span></a>
```

Mozilla Firefox:

```
<a href="javascript:makeRequest(getUrl(" 2018-02-05"),="" gettodayschapter);"=""><span class="date"><time datetime="2018-02-05">Mon Feb 05 2018</time></span> <span class="reference bookchapter">Amos 1</span></a>
```

Google Chrome:

```
<a href="javascript:makeRequest(getUrl(" 2018-02-05"),="" gettodayschapter);"=""><span class="date"><time datetime="2018-02-05">Mon Feb 05 2018</time></span> <span class="reference bookchapter">Amos 1</span></a>
```

Can anyone explain why all the browsers are inserting a space in `getUrl()` and adding the extra `=""`s?  And why is Edge flipping `date` and `getTodaysChapter`?

Oddly enough, if I remove the quotes around `date`, all three browsers output correctly.
But, I think I need to pass that parameter as a string (maybe the hyphens automatically make it a string).

```
<a href="javascript:makeRequest(getUrl(2018-02-05), getTodaysChapter);"><span class="date"><time datetime="2018-02-05">Mon Feb 05 2018</time></span> <span class="reference bookchapter">Amos 1</span></a>
```

Comment: well because you have nested quotes, how is the parser supposed to know it is not supposed to stop at the first closing "`" it finds?

Comment: You should **not** be using `<a>` elements just to initiate JavaScript. Links are for navigation. Your technique is about 20 years old. Just add a `click` event handler to the `span` tags directly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm sure it's not the best way to do it.  I'm working with what I know.  Once I get something that works, I will look into improving.  A lot of this should be done with object-oriented programming, binding, etc...  I'm just not there, yet.

Comment: @epascarello I see what you're talking about.  I ended up doing `getUrl(\'' + date + '\')`

Answer (score 0):

```
scheduleitems += '<li class=\"link\"><a href=\"javascript:makeRequest(getUrl(' + date.toString() + '), getTodaysChapter);\"><span class=\"date\"><time datetime=\"' + date.toString() + '\">' + datereadable + '<\/time><\/span> <span class=\"reference bookchapter\">' + book + ' ' + chapter + '<\/span><\/a><\/li>';
```